# Convert string '2*2*3*5' into an integer in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working with python 3, and I would like to convert a string like

> '2*2*3*5'

into the integer

> 2*2*3*5 = 60

I have a dictionary with a lot of strings like that, and I need to use them as integers. Is there a fast way to do this?
I have tought of using split but I'm having some trouble doing this.

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: You should **not** use `eval`. Have a look at this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string) instead.

Comment: Also, perhaps you could write a simple parser for your strings. Are your expressions more complex than just x*y*z ?

Comment: *eval* is not necessarily a bad thing.  It depends, of course, on the source of the data.  If they are from a static, carefully checked file than no solution can be more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

If it is acceptable to use eval (i.e., your data must be carefully checked in order to prevent unwanted execution of code), you can try:

```
str = '2*2*3*5'

print eval(str)
```

Comment: -1. With no background about the user or the source of the dict, suggesting `eval` with no caveats is irresponsible.

Answer (score 2):

If all your expressions are repeated multiplication, you can do it like this (no eval):

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> from operator import mul
>>> reduce(mul, [int(term) for term in '2*2*3*5'.split('*')])
60
```